# Symfony2 Semantical Error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problem with my Doctrine 2 query.

```
$this->qb->select('COUNT(offersCountsssssssssss.id) as offerCount')
    ->from('FactoryMainBundle:Offers', 'offersCountssssssssss');
$result = $this->qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I get error

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 133 near 'offersCounts': Error: 'offersCountsssssssssss' is already defined.

I changed the alias to very strange string but error is the same.
What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building this query in a repository class, you may omit the form method, because it does it automatically for you. So you can do it like this (or you can get the repository object and use it instead of $this):

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('offersCountssssssssss');
$query->select('COUNT(offersCountsssssssssss.id) as offerCount');
$result = $this->getQuery()->getResult();
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builder